# GCC AVR error: "expected ‘)’ before ‘>=’ token"

Tags: arduino, avr

I'm trying to upload code with [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) to ATtiny 2313 and I get an error:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/avr/4.7.2/../../../avr/include/util/delay.h:44:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/avr/4.7.2/../../../avr/include/avr/delay.h:37,
                 from /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tiny/cores/tiny/wiring_private.h:32,
                 from /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tiny/cores/tiny/WInterrupts.c:37:
/usr/lib/gcc/avr/4.7.2/../../../avr/include/math.h:426:15: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘double’
/usr/lib/gcc/avr/4.7.2/../../../avr/include/math.h:426:15: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘>=’ token
```

Even on a blank [sketch](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch).

Platform:

- IDE version: 1.03
- Arduino R3
- OS: [Ubuntu 13.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_13.04_.28Raring_Ringtail.29) (Raring Ringtail)

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you using an arduino as a programmer for a ATtiny? Or are you just trying put arduino code on a Attiny...(You can't put "arduino" code on a ATtiny) You could put a program written C on a ATtiny.

Comment: Yes, i'm using arduino as a programmer for ATtiny2313@8MHz. 
I know that, but this error displays even or simple C code or even blank sketch. Everytime :/

Answer (score 0):

A compile failure in a header such as this is likely caused by unintended macro results. My Arduino IDE 1.03 install only uses GCC 4.3.2, so cannot see your line 426 in math.h. The version of the compiler is likely your problem. Arduino ships with 4.3.2, but you have installed the leading edge 4.7.2 [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection).

You can try to workaround this error by forcing the order of header includes. Put

```
#include <math.h>
```

at the very top of your source file. That will cause it to be expanded before the other files and may eliminate the error. Shuffling file order to eliminate dependencies problems is not a best practice.

If you want to fix, look at line 426. Do a find in files for any text that looks like a macro define. You will likely find something in the tiny headers that is different from the other cores.